# Modify regex to validate email?

Tags: php, regex

`preg_match("/^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$/", $email);`

I want to modify this regex to allow emails such as *user+one@wherever.com*

How can I do this?

Comment: Mandatory link: [Mail::RFC822::Address: regexp-based address validation](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Do not use regex to validate email. [You will fail](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/regex-use-vs-regex-abuse.html).

Comment: (Also note that many real-world addresses do not satisfy RFC822.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `+` in the `[-\w.]` part:

```
preg_match("/^[-\w.+]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$/", $email);
```

Note that the filter extension has an email validator that can properly validate email addresses:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    // invalid
}
```

See [`filter_var`<sup>*[doc]*</sup>](http://php.net/filter_var) and the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`<sup>*[doc]*</sup>](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter.

FYI here is [the regex used by FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2c5b7026c03c74d5984ed1db19f94146ec3651d4/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L501):

```
/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})
(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?
:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22
(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-
\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3
F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5
D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[
a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]
+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(
?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f
0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]
{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?:
:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?
:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(
?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD
```

Comment: I would recommend not bothering to try RegEx, just stick with `filter_var`!

Comment: Mind linking to the manual page for filter_var (for reference)

Comment: @Aleks: It's been in the answer for some time :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `+` to the first character set:

```
preg_match("/^[-\w.+]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$/", $email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out a concern with the previous answers: '+' and '.' cannot be the first character in the username part of the email address. The correct regex should be

```
preg_match("/^\w[-\w.+]*@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$/", $email);
```

Note that in order to validate against the full RFC 2822, you'll need something like this:

```
preg_match('/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/', $email);
```

However this is not very practical for most application.  Have a look at [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for a detailed discussion of regex validation of email addresses.

Comment: '.' in the first set will not match any character, its in inside the character class selector [] so it will match only match the literal .