# How to check that there is only one "@" character in the string?

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify regex to validate email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443155/modify-regex-to-validate-email)

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

if(preg_match("[@{1}]",$email))
    echo "There is only one @ symbol";

if(preg_match("[@{2,}]",$email))
    echo "There is more than one";
```

It's simple my problem but since I've rarely used regular expressions the output doesn't come out the way I want. Also $email is the post data.

If $email has 2 or more @ symbols then it will display that there is more than one. If $email has 1 @symbol then it will display that there is only 1 @ symbol. Easy enough right?

Comment: You're missing delimiters.  It should be something like `~[@{1}]~`.  Although you also have the problem that the statements do not do what you think.

Comment: I've tried using else if's and didn't work either. Just adding that to the list of things I tried.

Comment: @Corbin: `[]` are delimiters in this case.

Comment: @Amadan Interesting.  Did not know that [] can be used as delimiters.  I always assume that it had to be a char that exactly matched as the second one.

Comment: @mwong This really is a misuse of regular expressions (they can be used to check if an email address is valid, but not like this).  What you're attempting here would be better realized with `strpos()`.

Comment: I know I could use strpos() but since this is my homework I kind of have to use regex since that's what I'm restricted to do.

Comment: I have written a [really brief regex introduction](http://xisb.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/what-absolutely-every-programmer-should-know-about-regular-expressions/), maybe it helps you to understand a bit more about regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first expression will match one `@` anywhere; it never says it needs to be the only one.

Your second expression will match two or more *consecutive* `@` signs. It will not detect the case when you have two that are separated by something else.

You need to translate the concept of "only one" or "more than one" into terms compatible with regexp:

- "only one": a single `@` surrounded by non-`@`: `^[^@]*@[^@]*$`
- "more than one": two `@` separated by anything: `@.*@`

and a related and also useful concept of "anything but only one" (i.e. 0, 2, 3, 4...) simply as negation of the first one (i.e. `!preg_match('/^[^@]*@[^@]*$/', $email)`)

Comment: Wow thank you that did work. But the thing I was wondering was why didn't {1} work? I thought that meant there's only one instance of a string?

Comment: No, `{n}` means "`n` repetitions of the previous pattern", as in right here right now. So for example `@{3}` matches `"a@@@b"` and `"a@@@@@b"` (it will only match the first three `@` chars, whereas `@{3,}` will match them all, but both will match) and also `"a@@@b@@@c"`, but fails on `"a@@b"` (there isn't three) and `"a@b@c@d"` (they're not consecutive). Regexps are completely local; there's no operator that says "in the whole string".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `explode` and `count` like that:

```
if (count(explode('@', $email)) > 2) {
    //here you have 2 or more
}
```

What is the goal you are trying to achieve? Do you really want to know whether there is only one `@` in it or do you want to validate the whole email address? If you want to validate it, have a look at this post: [Modify regex to validate email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443155/modify-regex-to-validate-email)

Comment: The thing is this is my homework and I can't use anything other than regex to validate forms.

Comment: yup, work's in php, can't argue with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to enclose your regex in delimiters like forward slash(/) or any other char.

$email = $_POST["email"];

if(preg_match("/[@{1}]/",$email))
    echo "There is only one @ symbol"."</br>";

//you have to use preg_match_all to match all chars because preg_match will stop at first occurence of match.

if(preg_match_all("/(\w*@)/",$email,$matches)){             //\w matches all alphanumeric chars, * means 0 or more occurence of preceeding char 
    echo "There is more than one"."</br>";
    print_r($matches);}                                 //$matches will be the array of matches found.
?>
```

Comment: check this if your requirement is met by this posted code as its simpler and easy to understand.